# How did "lunar" come to mean both the skin "mole" and the "moon" in Spanish and Portuguese?

Tags: etimología, lingüística, portugués

In Latin, "lunaris" relates to the moon. The word "lunar" in all the romance languages comes from Latin "lunaris". However, In Spanish and Portuguese, "lunar" can also mean the "mole" on the human skin. [I tried searching for a reliable source regarding this coincidence, but my search was unsuccessful](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=%22Spanish%22+%22Portuguese%22+%22lunar%22+%22mole%22+%22moon%22&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=lang_en&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&tbs=). How did Spanish and Portuguese end up using "lunar" for both the skin "mole" and the "moon"?

Comment: The Diccionario de la lengua española [says](https://dle.rae.es/lunar): "De Luna, porque se atribuía a influjo de este astro, o porque tenía su forma," i.e. either because birthmarks were attributed to the influence of the moon or they were perceived to have a moon-like shape.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel, doesn't that make a short, yet complete answer? The DLE is the single most authoritative source one can think of for dictionaries, which kind of reflects centralizing latino culture very well. There could be some more specialized source for etymologies like Corominas, but still the DLE is a pretty good source.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel apparently, Corominas also supports this thesis (cf https://www.elcastellano.org/palabra/luna). I'm trying to reach the original source right now.

Comment: I suspect that it is simply a "castellanicism" that has reached the Portuguese language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Los lunares reciben su nombre porque durante miles de años se creyó que se formaban en los niños por influencia de la Luna**.

Que el concepto de [**lunar**](https://dle.rae.es/lunar) ("Pequeña mancha en el rostro u otra parte del cuerpo, producida por una acumulación de pigmento en la piel", según el DLE) tiene su origen en la forma de nuestro satélite, la Luna, dan también buena prueba otros objetos que asimismo reciben su nombre por la misma razón.

Sirva este ejemplo, que creo es suficientemente indicativo:

> **[Luneta](https://dle.rae.es/luneta)**.
>
> 1. f. Cristal o vidrio pequeño que es la parte principal de los anteojos.
> 2. f. Cristal de un automóvil, en especial el posterior.
> 3. f. Círculo de oro, o de metal dorado, en que se encierra la sagrada hostia para ser expuesta a los fieles.

Y así, hasta 13 acepciones que hacen referencia a objetos cuya denominación se basa en la forma de nuestro satélite.

---

**Moles get their name because for thousands of years it was believed that they were formed in children by the influence of the Moon.**

The idea that [mole](https://dle.rae.es/lunar) ("Small spot on the face or other part of the body, produced by an accumulation of pigment in the skin", according to the DLE) have its origin in the shape of the Moon, also gives good proof other objects that also receive their name for same reason.

Take this example, which I think is indicative enough:

> **[Luneta](https://dle.rae.es/luneta)**.
>
> 1. f. Cristal o vidrio pequeño que es la parte principal de los anteojos.
> 2. f. Cristal de un automóvil, en especial el posterior.
> 3. f. Círculo de oro, o de metal dorado, en que se encierra la sagrada hostia para ser expuesta a los fieles.

And so, up to 13 meanings that refer to objects whose name is based on the shape of our satellite.

Comment: Also translate your answer in English as English is the primary language for many people like me.

Comment: I will tranlate later. Witch effort, but I will do it!

Comment: I have added the answer, now in English.

Comment: OK, but please, do not add multiple answers to the same question unless they are completely different, independent solutions to the same problem. You try merging you English answer to this one.

Comment: Sorry! I have merged it.

Comment: You don't have to translate it into English.

Comment: I did it, cause the OP asked me (look at first comment).

Answer (score 8):

[Corominas (1967)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/8424913329) says the following:

> "Lunar, adj., 1490; 'claro de luna', ant. S. XIV, de ahí, por comparación
> con una luna llena, parece haber pasado a designar una mancha más o menos
> redonda en el cuerpo del hombre o del caballo, sobre todo la que se tiene de nacimiento, 1495 (a base del nombre los astrólogos supusieron que pudiera ser debido al influjo de la luna sobre el niño en el gremio materno, de donde luego la generalización a lunares de todas formas y colores)

*Lunar, adj., 1490; 'moonlight' before the XIV cent. hence, by comparison with the full Moon, it seems to have started denoting a more or less round spot in the body of a man or horse, especially birthmarks, 1495 (based in the name, astrologists assumed they were caused by the Moon's influence over the baby in its mother's womb, whence later generalized to all shapes and colors of moles)*

Note that according to this, *lunar* would probably come from *luna* from Spanish rather than directly from Latin, since Spanish by the XV century was already well established.

The Diccionario de la Lengua Española (DLE) agrees with Corominas when stating the etymology of [*lunar*](https://dle.rae.es/lunar) (mole), as Sebastian noted in the comments:

> De Luna, porque se atribuía a influjo de este astro, o porque tenía su forma.

*(from Moon, because it was attributed to this celestial body's influence, or because it had its shape.)*

It isn't obvious in which source(s) did Corominas base his claim, or if it was just a most-educated guess/opinion, but these (Corominas and the DLE) are currently the two most authoritative sources for Spanish that one can think of.

Answer (score 4):

According to Covarrubias and his etymological dictionary from 1611:

> Se dixo por ser efeto de la luna,o porque se fixa en el rostro, o en otra parte, como la luna en su Orbe.

A definition a bit confusing, maybe, but the *Diccionario de Autoridades* from 1734 clarifies it:

> Se pudo llamar lunar, por ser efecto de la Luna, o por las manchas que en la Luna se perciben.

So the origin of the name could be:

- Moles (or birthmarks) are created by the influence of the Moon, or
- Moles are fixed in your face (or any other place) as the stains you see on the Moon's face with your naked eye. So for Covarrubias the reason was not that the moles were round as the Moon, but rather that moles remind of the apparent stains of the Moon (a darker spot over a lighter skin).

The word is older than we may think. It is already present in Nebrija's dictionary from 1495:

[image: Nebrija's translation of 'Lunar']

The first definition is for the moonlight, and the second and third for the moles/birthmarks.

Also, searching for the word *lunar* in CORDE I have found it is already present in the fourth part of *General Estoria*, written by Alfonso X in 1280:

> Et molio del caruon. Et fizol con el un lunar negro en la fruent.

Translated:

> Then she ground the coal and drew with it a black mole on his forehead.

So, given that the word *lunar* is already present in Spanish texts from the XIII century, it may have been used well before that, around the origins of the Old Spanish language in the IX century.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

---

La cuestión en sí sería algo más compleja; **¿Cómo terminaron los españoles y portugueses usando "lunar" tanto para referirse a las manchas de la piel como al dibujo en forma de lunar que recibe el nombre de "topo" y al sentido "lunar" de la Luna?. En definitiva, ¿ por qué el lunar como mancha, se llama lunar ?.**

---

**Planteamiento**

Tradicionalmente se han buscado distintas razones que expliquen cual es la procedencia de la palabra "lunar" como mancha, así se dice que los "lunares" reciben su nombre por el influjo que la Luna obra sobre las personas y la influencia que tiene ésta sobre ellas, por la forma circular de la "Luna", por las manchas que en la Luna aparecen o porque durante miles de años se pensó en la fuerza que esta ejercía sobre la aparición de esas manchas sobre la piel. Sin embargo, un detenimiento pausado sobre la cuestión hace que nos interroguemos si no es ésta una fórmula simplemente popular de enlazar onomatopéyicamente las palabras "Luna" y "lunar" con esos "lunares" como "defectos" en la piel o si es posible sopesar que exista otro tipo de vinculación que desconocemos.

La palabra "lunar" para referirse a tales manchas es relativamente reciente y el latín utilizado en el Imperio Romano no recoge "lunar" como acepción para aludir a ellas. Esto hace plantearse varias cuestiones. Si lo que hoy llamamos "lunares", se llamasen por ejemplo, "solares" y al "lunar", "solar", ¿pensaríamos entonces que su nombre procedería del sol? e igualmente ¿diríamos que es por el influjo "solar", por su forma circular, por las manchas que existen en él, etc?, es decir, que lo mismo que en la actualidad se afirma para enlazar estos argumentos con la Luna servirían entonces para hacerlo con el Sol. Además, el color negro, marrón o rojo de éstos incluso estarían más próximos a admitir esa relación con el astro "Sol" que con la "Luna", pues una "Luna" obscura por si sola si no existen otras razones es difícil de sostener.

Por tanto, algo inducía a pensar que en ese fácil encuentro narrativo, "luna-lunar", faltaban o había partes incompletas aún sin determinar. Así la relación entre una mancha, ya sea como marca o en su sentido de impureza o vergüenza y la Luna debería ser mucho más antigua, expresiones griegas como λύμα (luma) con el significado de suciedad, mancha, vergüenza, impureza, agua usada en una lavadura o purificación y otras palabras y Dioses griegos o del latín palabras como "luo" (lavar, pagar una deuda, expiar una culpa...) caracterizaban esta lejanía y esa relación.

En la simbología antigua Cristiana, el Sol y la Luna, se relacionaron con Adán y Eva. Eva "persuadida por la serpiente" comió la manzana (malum) del árbol del conocimiento y pecó contra Dios, perdiendo por ello aquella "Gracia" con la que Dios la había bendecido. Quizás éstas historias correspondan a leyendas más antiguas, recogidas, asimiladas y adaptadas por el Cristianismo, aunque desde entonces y como consecuencia de aquello para las nuevas generaciones de Cristianos la Luna fue considerada figurativamente poseedora de una "mancha", una "vergüenza", que en parte enlazaba con aquel primer "pecado original". Con el avance y evolución del Cristianismo, en la luz del Sol iluminando y dando su luz a la "Luna", se querrá ver a "Dios" iluminando la "Gracia" otorgada a María, "Anunciación de María", (annuntiatio) y la llegada del "Salvador". Con este nuevo sentido aparecerán representaciones alegóricas de "Vírgenes Negras" que simbolizan la mancha del pecado junto con las figuras de la Luna y la serpiente postradas ahora a los pies de la Virgen como signo de victoria sobre el mal, pues María Santísima de la Inmaculada Concepción ha sido preservada y exenta de cualquier "mancha" e iluminada por la "Gratia Plena" de Dios, concebida sin pecado original, que ahora anuncia la llegada del redentor.

La búsqueda de motivos distintos a los ya clásicos, por los fundamentos expresados, han sido sin duda la razón de esta mini investigación que intenta ayudar a entender, entre otras ideas, el por qué al lunar de la piel se le llama lunar y existiendo una relación anterior, entre la Luna y una mancha, qué es lo que le ha llevado a ese nombre actual de "lunar" a ser interpretado como una mancha sobre el cuerpo.

---

**Resumen**

Quizás hablar "del sentido lunar de la Luna", sea la cuestión más fácil de responder, pues todo aquello que es relativo o perteneciente a la Luna es lunar. Lunaris. Annus lunaris civilis, en este sentido, "lunar", pertenecería o estaría de alguna manera, relacionado con la "Luna". Sin embargo, ¿por qué escoger la forma de una "Luna Llena" (Plenilunio), para referirse a una mancha circular de la piel, cuando teóricamente las figuras más característica de la Luna son otras, y sin duda ésta, la "Luna Llena", por sí sola no representa a la Luna en su totalidad?. La cuestión así planteada adolecía aquel sentido de forma. ¿La fusión  de ambos conceptos fue solo por el nombre, o existe otra relación que no habíamos visto y que vinculaba el nombre "lunar" de manera dispar ?.

Por otra parte, las otras dos cuestiones planteadas podían ayudar a entender ese otro tipo de relación. "Lunar" como mancha en la piel y "topo" no procederían directamente de la Luna, sino de un concepto relacionado con ella, el eclipse y la interposición de un cuerpo, en este caso la Luna, que sirve de obstáculo o impedimento interpolado, el cual se ve como una gran mancha que obscurece la Tierra.  La Luna bloquea la luz del Sol y proyecta una sombra o mancha "Lunar" sobre la superficie de la Tierra. Este "Defectus", (Eclipse), se interpretará posteriormente como un "defecto", igual que una imperfección, una marca, una sombra o mancha que se tiene sobre la piel y aquella vieja relación entre una "Mancha" y la "Luna" recibirá por esa misma razón el nombre de "lunar".

En este mismo sentido los "Topos o Lunares" también llamados Bodoques en costura, proceden de "Tope", "Topar" plural "Topes-Topos" y responde a ese mismo sentido de "eclipse" como estorbo, impedimento u obstáculo que encuentra una dificultad para que, en este caso la luz, llegue al lugar que corresponde. Metafóricamente en otros contextos sería simplemente encontrar, hallar una dificultad, persistir en ella o tener una mancha como rémora, atascamiento o embarazo.
Por tanto una blusa llena de topos (lunares), es una blusa figurativamente, que esta llena de obstáculos, representados por cada una de esas "sombras o manchas" que aparecen en su dibujo.
En su evolución e interpretación, este sentido de "obstáculo", se transformó en otro tipo de obstáculos como son cerros y colinas.

[image]

---

**Definición de Lunar**

- Mancha pequeña, redondeada, de color marrón oscuro y a veces ligeramente abultada, que sale en la piel del cuerpo humano por acumulación de células pigmentarias.
- Porción pequeña de pelos de distinto color en el pelaje de ciertos animales.

---

**Sentido Etimológico y Figurativo de las Palabras**

En etimología no solo cuenta el sentido estricto de las palabras sino la imagen o esencia psíquica del significante y las relaciones mentales que las personas establecen entre ellas para después, y a partir de ahí, seguir evolucionando.

El lenguaje evolucionado a lo largo de sus etapas puede convertirse en figurativo y expresar y relacionar pensamientos abstractos con sentidos distintos a aquellos formulados de forma estricta.

Así podemos decir;

- María defiende a su familia como una leona acosada.
- La televisión es un nido de serpientes.
- No eres un burro pero rebuznas.
- Me morí del susto.
- Me enfade con él y cruce el charco.
- Puedo fiarme totalmente de Pedro, él es una tumba.

Como se ve, en el lenguaje figurado que utilizamos se establece algún tipo de semejanza que a su vez guarda cierta relación con otra palabra, un concepto, una idea o incluso una emoción. Así, una voz según el contexto o la intención puede valerse de cualquier idea o motivo con la que guarda determinada analogía ya sea real o aparezca en el imaginario colectivo y expresando en muchos casos un sentido opuesto o distinto al literal y que a su vez puede ir evolucionando e incorporando nuevos contenidos y que muchas de las veces no suelen ser recogidos por los diccionarios.

---

**Luna - Lunar en Latín**

- En latín tenemos el verbo "luno" 1 tr. encorvar en forma de luna. También la palabra "lunaris" - e, lunar, de forma de luna o incluso la palabra "luna - ae", luna.
- Como cognomen (especificaba la rama de la familia (nomen) a la que pertenecía, también era utilizado como apodo), "Lunaris", aunque aparece en algunas inscripciones romanas en lápidas y altares, no era muy frecuente y aún menos utilizado con el significado de sombra o mancha en la piel. En España, (lunaris (AE 217, 962; CIL XIII 4387), Lunaris (Solin - Salomies 1988,353), en Inglaterra RIB 1521. Altar dedicado a Belleticaurus y RIB 786. Inscripción funeraria para Pluma.
- Igualmente en latín hallamos la palabra "naevus - i" que significa lunar, mancha, verruga, marca de nacimiento... Como se ha indicado en otra respuesta, esta palabra "naevus - ", paso al latín hispánico (España y Portugal), y recogidas en su diccionario por Nebrija como "neuus - i", lunar, señal del cuerpo y "neuulus - i", lunar pequeño.

Actualmente "neuus" ha pasado al español preferentemente como término médico "nevus o nevo" (lunar), proliferación en la piel, una lesión benigna (no cancerosa). Generalmente un "nevo" es oscuro y a veces "sobresale" de la piel y obviamente también se llama lunar.

- Es curioso que la Diosa Lua (se cree que es una variante del nombre de Luna), (*Lua Saturni*), fuera aquella ante la que expiar una culpa o pagar una deuda y a la que se ofrecían las armas de los enemigos derrotados. Para algunos estudiosos estaría relacionado con el verbo "luo", pagar una deuda, alejar las calamidades con la expiación e igualmente relacionado con un hipotético *luõ, con el significado de «manchar», considerándola una divinidad perniciosa de la destrucción, del holocausto, de la muerte y de las impurezas en nexo con las «manchas» de tipo religioso («pol-luo», «lutum», λύμα).
- Macula - ae, marca, punto, malla de una red, mácula, mancha, ignominia, infamia. fig. pecado.
- Ceremonia de la "lustratio" o purificación pública. Los censores se convertían en vigilantes de la moral pública. Pedían cuentas a los ciudadanos de conductas dudosas y recibían reprimendas por ellos (notae). Sus mandatos duraban cinco años y al término del mismo se celebraba esta ceremonia.

[image]

- Tipo de Objeto: Altar
- Origen del texto: Carrawburgh
- Tipo de Documento: RIB 1521. Altar dedicado a Belleticaurus
- Fecha: 43-410 d.C.
- Texto en Latín: Deo Belleticauro Lunaris
- Traducción: Al Dios Belleticaurus Lunaris
- Lugar: Inglaterra

---

**Términos Figurados**

Visto lo anterior, se deduce que tuvo que existir un trasvase de contenido entre la palabra "nevus y lunar" para especificar una misma cosa, siendo la utilización de "lunar" con el sentido de "mancha", más tardía.

Una vez fijados los primeros términos latinos, estos se fueron desarrollando a lo largo de la Edad Media y evolucionando con su sentido metafórico o figurativo que pueden aportar las palabras e imágenes que al respecto podían poseer aquella sociedad.

Así tenemos que la voz "nevus" se refiere a una mancha o señal que puede aparecer en el rostro u otra parte del cuerpo, estas manchas o sombras suelen ser de color negro, pardo o rojo. Covarrubias, como indicó, pensaba que "lunar" podría ser llamado así por efecto de la Luna o por las manchas que en la Luna se perciben, pero como se deja ver, no fue así, ya que la asimilación conceptual " nevus - lunaris " parece que fue más tardía y por otra parte Covarrubias no explicaba el ¿por qué de escoger esta figura que teóricamente representaría a una "Luna llena" cuando las formas característica de la Luna y la que la diferencia de otros astros es precisamente su popular silueta del luna menguante y luna creciente ?. No tenía mucho sentido asociar ese influjo a la Luna o a otro tipo de especulaciones encaminadas en esa misma dirección, definiendo la forma redondeada como "silueta tipo" de la Luna, cuando más bien el parecido de un "lunar" contrastaría mejor con otro astro, el Sol, que con la misma Luna.

"Nevus" y la asimilación posterior con el concepto "Lunar", recibió igualmente la forma metafórica y figurativa referida "a la nota, a la mancha o infamia que resulta de haber dicho o ejecutado alguna cosa fea y detestable".

Por tanto, esa "**mancha**" primaria de "Nevus" y luego de "Lunar", pasó también a significar de forma figurada algo inoportuno que frena o bloquea la fama y el talento y desacredita la honorabilidad de una persona o una familia. Es poner sucia una cosa con manchas figuradas, dañar e interponerse figurativamente entre esa sombra (de duda) y el buen nombre de la persona o su linaje.

Así la mancha se convierte en un defecto, una imperfección, una falta que la persona o la familia posee y que aún puede arrastrar esta carencia toda su vida, o incluso lastrarla durante generaciones.

De esta manera la expresión posterior como "Mancha o Lunar",  que hace referencia a una "mancha redonda en la piel", como defecto de la piel, en ausencia o cumulo de diversos pigmentos, se convirtió socialmente también, con este paralelismo figurativo de imperfección, en una "mancha o sombra negra" que obstaculiza, embarra, ensucia y destiñe el honor o fama de ciertas personas (oveja negra) y familias.

Pero, ¿ qué tiene que ver esto con la Luna ?.

---

**Tener un Defecto es como tener una Mancha**

Parece que primero fue "nevus" como mancha y después "lunar" el que recogió las distintas acepciones de aquel.

*Un defecto puede ser considerado como fallo o imperfección física, moral o intelectual de una persona. Ausencia de alguna propiedad o cualidad de algo.*

En la antigüedad los eclipses eran considerados en si mismos una forma de comunicación, mensajes que enviaban los Dioses a través del cielo, la palabra misma "eclipse", ἔκλειψις, (ékleipsis), deriva de la expresión griega que significa "abandono", el oscurecimiento de un cuerpo celeste, "oscurecerse", "dejar de existir" y hace referencia a la desaparición momentánea del astro.

En Latín, el eclipse era llamado "**defectus - us**", de sol "**Solis defectus**" y si era de Luna "**Lunae defectus**".

La palabra "defecto" en español procede precisamente del latín "defectus-us", que en un principio y entre otras cosas significaba "desaparición" (desaparición del sol, desaparición de la luna), en los sentidos de faltar, de no estar, carecer de algo. Cuando la luna o el sol "desaparecían", faltaba algo. Igualmente se aplicaba al desmayo, agotamiento, debilidad, flaqueza de fuerzas, como si el Sol o la Luna, (defectio - onis d. solis, d. lunae), también ellos tuvieran o participaran de esta debilidad o flaqueza al eclipsarse. Esta "falta de", también era considerada como "imperfección de", cuando faltaba algo o se carecía de algo.

En la Rae aún encontramos "Defecto" entre otras acepciones como, 1. Carencia de alguna cualidad propia de algo. 2. m. Imperfección en algo o en alguien. 3. m. Diferencia por la que algo no alcanza el límite debido o tomado como referencia.

Sin embargo, con los cambios sociales y la influencia religiosa la palabra "Defectus" para la gran masa social se torno en un sentido distinto al inicial, paso a ser considerado como algo defectuoso, imperfecto en el sentido de "defectivus - a - um". Así "defecto", se transformó en un "vicio", en una desviación de lo que era correcto, en un malestar. Se paso simplemente de carecer de una cualidad, a carecer de una cualidad virtuosa, y por tanto, sinónimo de algo malo, una falta, una sombra, una tacha, una "mancha" que examinaba las deficiencias en la persona, de esta manera, los defectos serían el origen del mal y de la malicia del deseo.

**De esta manera los antiguos significados de la voz "neuus" referidos a una mancha y el nuevo concepto de "defectus" como "defecto" y que aún mantenía la vieja imagen de "eclipse" (defectus) como obstáculo, sombra, mancha o cuerpo circular, se fusionaron para expresar igualmente esas imperfecciones de la piel**.

---

[image]

**Defecto como Mancha, Mancha como Lunar, Lunar como Defecto**.

Los eclipses eran para las antiguas sociedades una señal que podía anunciar enfermedades, terremotos y muerte. Considerados como un mal augurio y de las más graves y negativas profecías. Por tanto en este contexto, no fue muy difícil asociar la palabra "Defectus" a nuevas interpretaciones de índole negativa y religiosa.

Así, la palabra "Defectus" como "defectus solis" o "defectus lunae", en ese traspaso de nuevas relaciones que van incorporando las palabras en su evolución comentadas al principio, dejó de utilizarse en su acepción de "**Eclipse**" para pasar a referirse a aquello que era considerado o era poseedor de un "Defecto", esa "mancha lunar" provocada por la Luna "Defectus" (eclipse) ahora su sombra, también entraba dentro de la categoría de los "Defectos".

Los nevus, las manchas, los lunares llamados así por aquella razón y defectos fueron considerados con el mismo sentido de imperfecciones, desperfectos y deficiencias que salían en la piel. La superstición, las practicas adivinatorias, la brujería y su relación con la Luna y los lunares se agudizó, así por ejemplo, las personas que poseían determinadas marcas o pecas eran consideradas mentirosas o propensas a engañar.

Los nombres como " nevus, manchas o lunares" eran sinónimos de "defecto", de un mal, e igualmente de algo sucio que podría hallarse tanto en el interior de una persona como en el apellido de su linaje, así también en la superficie de la piel o en cualquier otro lugar que pudiera tener imperfecciones. Defectos manchas, sombras y lunares fueron una misma cosa.

**El término "Defectus" (Eclipse) y su relación con la voz "Defecto", sería la razón por la que las sombras, manchas y lunares de la piel están conectadas con ese sentido de la Luna o "mancha lunar" que como cuerpo o astro interpuesto, expande su mancha o sombra sobre la Tierra**.

---

**Topos**

[image]

El concepto de "Topos" podría ser engañoso, pues puede referirse a varios aspectos.

- "Topo" del cumanagoto (Quechua) "topo", como piedra redonda.
- Persona de cortos alcances que en todo yerra o se equivoca.
- Persona que tropieza en cualquier cosa por cortedad de vista o por desaliento natural.

Existen otras voces relativas e interesantes como topar y topear que enlazan con ese sentido inicial de encontrar un obstáculo o dificultad.

- "Topar" Chocar una cosa con otra. Hallar o encontrar lo que se anda buscando. Hallar casualmente o sin solicitud.
- "Topetar" *Querer. Consistir o estribar una cosa en otra y embarazar en ella. La dificultad topa en esto. Tropezar o embarazarse en algo, por algún obstáculo o dificultad. Tropezar o reparar en algo, advirtiendo alguna falta. Salir bien una cosa*.
- "Topetar" Dar con la cabeza en alguna cosa con golpe e impuso, lo cual se dice con propiedad de los carneros y otros animales cornudos.

Era, durante los segundos o minutos que duraba un eclipse solar total y la Luna bloqueaba por completo al Sol, cuando realmente se desataba el pánico, ya que no se sabia muy bien lo que estaba sucediendo. Algunos pensaban que los astros chocarían, que topaban entre sí, otros que un astro se comía a otro... Estos "topos" eran en definitiva interposiciones u obstáculos en el camino de otro astro cuya consecuencia más palpable era un impedimento y la ausencia de luz. Es por lo que los "topos" son ese tipo de objeto que están bloqueando u obstaculizando algo, por lo que como se dijo al principio, un traje por ejemplo lleno de topos (lunares), figurativamente estaría lleno de obstáculos, representados por cada una de esas "sombras o manchas" que aparecen en su dibujo.

El concepto de "Topos" fue evolucionando y aquellos primeros "obstáculos", se convirtieron en cerros y colinas, recogido en el Diccionario Histórico de la Lengua Española;

- "TOPO". (Del port.). m. Colina o cerro.

> 11-i-1525 (1988) Protocolos de R. Fernández (1449, p.596): *El pedazo
> de tierra linda por la parte de abajo con el acequia nueva del molino
> de Cristóbal de Ponte, por arriba con el risco que está arriba de la
> ladera, por una parte con un topo de una rocha que está en dicha
> hacienda* [...].
>
> ```
>     a1938 Pestana Vocabulario palmero (p.33): Topo. Terreno prominente.
> ```
>
> ¨Cita Pérez Vidal Portugueses (p.172) un verso de «una versión de La
> Infantina más El Nacimiento, recogida en Puntallana», que contiene la
> palabra: «Allá enría en aquel topo». Y añade que «En el término
> municipal de Garafía, en la misma isla, existen el Topo de las
> Perdomas, el Topo del Valle y el Topo de Salvatierra, caseríos,
> Olive». El que se encuentre también esta palabra en Venezuela es muy
> posible que se deba a la presencia de los canarios en aquella
> república. Núñez/Pérez la define como «Colina que se destaca en una
> sierra de escasa elevación». Vid. también Richard.

También existe el pez topo, igualmente llamado pez luna.

Los topos como animales y la semejanza que se ha querido advertir en sus madrigueras, no tendrían nada que ver con su razón original.

[image]

Comment: I need an English translation for every answer.

Comment: "This question was migrated from Latin Language Stack Exchange because it can be answered on Spanish Language Stack Exchange". Entiendo que puedo responder en Español. No obstante, puede" traducir la página" o simplemente llevar el "Resumen" que aparece al principio del artículo con esa intención y trasladarlo a un traductor, pues mi nivel de Inglés no alcanza tales cotas. Gracias.